# Select and show selected range of values in JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

At this URL are 100 sets of values in an array.  Have tried everything my limited brain can think of to access and show (to show myself it worked) this "`percent_change_24h`" value of JUST the first `0..10`- in hopes of gathering the average.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/',
            function (data) {
                document.body.append(data[0].percent_change_24h);
            });
    });
</script>
```

What I currently have of course just shows the first of `100`.  Figure there has to be a better way than stacking that line on top of itself with a `+1` each time to `10`.

Comment: you want to access first 10 or you want do show 10 at a time and with some click of a button show the next 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/',
    function (data) {
      var i, total = 0.00;
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
        total += Number(data[i].percent_change_24h);
      }
      document.body.append((total/10).toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

Comment: Is a for loop necessary? There is no more succinct way? Also, what is the .toFixed(2) for?

Comment: I think `for` loop is the most succinct way to go for sequential search. Optionally, you can use `while` and `for...in` loop also. But I am not sure you would get the same performance as `for` loop. I used `.toFixed(2)` to show the result in 2 decimal places on calculated average number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the optional parameters available for the CoinMarketCap JSON API Endpoint: `/ticker/`

- `(int) start` - return results from rank [start] and above
- `(int) limit` - return a maximum of [limit] results (default is 100, use 0 to return all results)

and just retrieve 10 records at a time and then the next 10 you can build the url like `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?start=0&limit=10` and then increment the start by 10 after every click. See a demo the retrieves 10 records every time and when clicking again next 10 records.

```js
var start = 0;
var limit = 10;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dynamic").on('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?start=' + start + '&limit=' + limit,
      function(data) {
        console.clear();
        for (var currencies in data) {
          if (data.hasOwnProperty(currencies)) {
            console.log(data[currencies].name, data[currencies].percent_change_24h);
            //document.body.append(data[currencies].percent_change_24h);
          }
        }
        start += limit;
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="dynamic">With Limit and start parameter </button>
```

Also you should notice the use of `for..in` loop for iterating over an object.The `for...in` statement iterates a specified variable over all the enumerable properties of an object. For each distinct property, JavaScript executes the specified statements.

Comment: Thank you for the above and beyond response, but was just looking for a top 10 average.

Comment: You are welcome @Alex, but your question title was emphasizing the selecting of the range of records, thought the average was not the problem but the selection of records, any way you solved it.